# ClassNotFoundException Symfony UserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm developping a website on Symfony2, I want to intergrate FOSUserBundle. I am using Doctrine ORM User class. I've followed the [installation steps](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md) but I got this error:

```
ClassNotFoundException in AppKernel.php line 21:
Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?
```

AppKernel.php:

```
    public function registerBundles()
{
    $bundles = array(
        ...
        new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
    );
```

It looks correctly placed: FOSUserBundle.php is located in **\vendor\friendsofsymfony\userbundle**

And the namespace is correct I think: **namespace FOS\UserBundle;**

Other files:

#config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: REMERA\PlatformBundle\Entity\User
```

#routing.yml

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

#security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager # Use form.csrf_provider instead for Symfony <2.4
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I've been trying to solve this for hours, answers on other similar questions don't resolve my error. Am I missing something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have dumped an autoloader earlier ? Try `php composer.phar dump-autoload --optimize`

Comment: It doens't seem to be this, the error is persisting

Comment: try to clear the cache first. Then if it is still not working, composer remove, composer require and composer update again.

Comment: Thank you, that solved ClassNotFoundException. I now have another error that I'll try to solve on my own first haha...
Would you mind explaining what was my problem? I don't fully understand

Comment: Clearing the cache often solves issues that you don't understand... Caching is really a complicated thing, so well... I don't know neither ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How this was solved:

try to clear the cache first. Then if it is still not working, composer remove, composer require and composer update again. –  [Brewal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2168947/brewal)

Answer (score 0):

When you try to clear cache but its not getting cleared you should use `--no-warmup` option, this will make sure that you cache is re-generated and cache is not warmed up only. I think this can help you:

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-warmup
```

or

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-warmup
```