# ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle" from namespace "FOS\UserBundle"

Tags: php, symfony, sonata, sonata-user-bundle

(Using WampServer on Windows 10.)

I followed the official documentation in order to install Sonata User Bundle over Symfony.

I get the following error message

> (1/1) ClassNotFoundException Attempted to load class "FOSUserBundle"
>   from namespace "FOS\UserBundle". Did you forget a "use" statement for
>   another namespace?

**AppKernel.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new AppBundle\AppBundle(),

            new Sonata\CoreBundle\SonataCoreBundle(),

            //Added following https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/getting_started/installation.html
            new Sonata\BlockBundle\SonataBlockBundle(),
            new Knp\Bundle\MenuBundle\KnpMenuBundle(),
            new Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle(),
            new Sonata\AdminBundle\SonataAdminBundle(),

            //Added following https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends/2-x/doc/reference/installation.html
            new Sonata\EasyExtendsBundle\SonataEasyExtendsBundle(),

            //Added following https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
            new Sonata\UserBundle\SonataUserBundle('FOSUserBundle'),


        ];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();

            if ('dev' === $this->getEnvironment()) {
                $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
                $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle();
            }
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function getRootDir()
    {
        return __DIR__;
    }

    public function getCacheDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/'.$this->getEnvironment();
    }

    public function getLogDir()
    {
        return dirname(__DIR__).'/var/logs';
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en

framework:
    #esi: ~
    #translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }
    secret: '%secret%'
    router:
        resource: '%kernel.project_dir%/app/config/routing.yml'
        strict_requirements: ~
    form: ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation: { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer: { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale: '%locale%'
    trusted_hosts: ~
    session:
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id: session.handler.native_file
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
    fragments: ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_host%'
        port: '%database_port%'
        dbname: '%database_name%'
        user: '%database_user%'
        password: '%database_password%'
        charset: UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path: '%database_path%'
        types:
            json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        entity_managers:
            default:
                mappings:
                    ApplicationSonataUserBundle: ~
                    SonataUserBundle: ~
                    FOSUserBundle: ~                                    # If SonataUserBundle extends it

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: '%mailer_transport%'
    host: '%mailer_host%'
    username: '%mailer_user%'
    password: '%mailer_password%'
    spool: { type: memory }

#Sonata
sonata_core:
    form_type: horizontal

sonata_user:
    security_acl: true
    manager_type: orm # can be orm or mongodb

sonata_block:
    default_contexts: [cms]
    blocks:
        # enable the SonataAdminBundle block
        sonata.admin.block.admin_list:
            contexts: [admin]
        #...
        sonata.user.block.menu:    # used to display the menu in profile pages
        sonata.user.block.account: # used to display menu option (login option)
        sonata.block.service.text: # used to if you plan to use Sonata user routes

#FOSUser
fos_user:
    db_driver:      orm # can be orm or odm
    firewall_name:  main
    user_class:     Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseUser

    group:
        group_class:   Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\BaseGroup
        group_manager: sonata.user.orm.group_manager                    # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.group_manager for mongodb)

    service:
        user_manager: sonata.user.orm.user_manager                      # If you're using doctrine orm (use sonata.user.mongodb.user_manager for mongodb)
```

**routing.yml**

```
login_view:
    path:     '/login/'
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Login:view }

singlesingon_view:
    path:     '/authentication/singlesignon/'
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:AuthenticationSingleSignOn:view }

singlesingout_view:
    path:     '/authentication/singlesignout/'
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:AuthenticationSingleSignOut:view }    

app:
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/'
    type: annotation

admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_security:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_security.xml'
    prefix: /admin

sonata_user_admin_resetting:
    resource: '@SonataUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/admin_resetting.xml'
    prefix: /admin/resetting
```

When I reach step 2.5 which starts with running

```
php bin/console sonata:easy-extends:generate SonataUserBundle -d src
```

I get

> Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found.

---

As requested in comments: autoload section of composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "AppBundle\\": "src/AppBundle"
    },
    "classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
```

Comment: Have you installed it / added it with composer?

Comment: Yes, as mentionned in the guide.

Comment: clear caches, update fos user bundle also check here [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863601/classnotfoundexception-symfony-userbundle)

Comment: can you add the autoload code to your post

Comment: @Melik: Where do I find the autoload ?

Comment: composer.json  : "autoload"

Comment: @Mert: Thank you, I read that thread. But I not sure when they say remove, re-require, update if they are talking about FOSUserBundle or SonataUserBundle.

Comment: Actually does not matter, because sonata using Fos User right ? updating fos user may help you. did you achieved it already ? it yes lets check other solutions :)

Comment: @MélikZarkouna : autoload added at bottom of the question

Comment: @MertÖksüz : Yes I have already tried to update FOS and Sonata User Bundle. Same error still.

Comment: try my answer !

Comment: yes try first that answer lets see :)

Comment: Tried, didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

In composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { 
            "": "src/", 
            "Application": "app/" 
        }
    },
```

than Update Composer :

```
composer update
```

if this dont work so try to fix the bundle by this command :

```
php app/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle
```

Extend base user FosUser :

```
class Myusers extends BaseUser
{
}
```

In config.yml

```
fos_user:
    user_class: MyBundle\Entity\Myusers
```

Comment: Tried to change autoload. No success. Can you explain what this change was supposed to do ?

Tried second solution: Still Fatal error: Class 'FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle' not found in (...)AppKernel.php on line 32.

Comment: it's to save the bundles in the src directory ! you  updated the composer ?

Comment: okey so delete the path  /vendor/friendsofsymfony/ than update Fosuser

Comment: There is no friendsofsymfony in vendor. ... Maybe I can download it manually ? (if even possible?)

Comment: sure you can ! i suggest to forget about sonata admin just install fosuser the last version and if you have a prob with it i m here . i m glad to help you

Comment: So, I should undo all the installation guide?
Actually, I've tried to find informations of the concrete advantages of SonataUserBundle over using simply FOSUserBundle ... but all I got was somebody who replied that SonataUserBundle has more functionnalities ...
So if you know the actual differences, I would be interested.

Comment: yes , true sonataUserbundle contain fosuser and have more functionnalities like admin stuff , if you only want reg,login,and users it is not worth to install sonata fosuser can do the job

Comment: If I install only FOS, can I extend it later, with existing users ?

Comment: sure i will add an example how to extend the baseUser  in the answer

Comment: What I meant by "extending" was "to install SonataUserBundle extending FOS". But extending users may be quite interesting too.

Comment: I think it is possible but you should do it manually  and change lot of configurations files